# zmq_send() blocks on recv()/poll()

Tags: c, zeromq

I try to send a few small (8 byte) messages through inproc pair socket. However after a few tries zmq_send() blocks. When I stop debugger I see following stack trace:

```
libc.so.6!__GI___poll(struct pollfd * fds, nfds_t nfds, int timeout) 
libzmq.so.5!poll(int __timeout, nfds_t __nfds, pollfd * __fds) 
libzmq.so.5!zmq::signaler_t::wait(zmq::signaler_t * const this, int timeout_) 
libzmq.so.5!zmq::mailbox_t::recv(zmq::mailbox_t * const this, zmq::command_t * cmd_, int timeout_) 
libzmq.so.5!zmq::socket_base_t::process_commands(zmq::socket_base_t * const this, int timeout_, bool throttle_) 
libzmq.so.5!zmq::socket_base_t::send(zmq::socket_base_t * const this, zmq::msg_t * msg_, int flags_) 
libzmq.so.5!s_sendmsg(int flags_, zmq_msg_t * msg_, zmq::socket_base_t * s_) 
libzmq.so.5!zmq_send(void * s_, const void * buf_, size_t len_, int flags_)
```

Why does it happen? What commands does ZMQ try to to process? Why does it call recv()? Is it because of high water mark? I suppose it's something different because I send small amount of data and water mark shouldn't be reached yet. And if water mark is the only explanation then how can I measure it?

Comment: What type of zmq_socket are you using?  What flags are you specifying?  The behavior is very sock-type specific.

Comment: Without seeing your code it is difficult to guess what's wrong. Please [edit] your question and show a [mre].

Comment: @ChrisDodd it's inprox pair, as in the question. There are no flags.

Comment: @Bodo I'll try, but the code is quite large. I observed that _pipe is NULL so zmq::pair_t::xsend() returns -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was bug in logic of my code. After sending some messages, next were sent by different thread using different socket. That socket was not connected so zmq_send() was waiting for connection to be established. This is why its pipe was NULL. Thanks everybody for help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this will happen when the socket reaches some sort of limit on outstanding sent data; it will then block waiting for an acknowledgement message allowing it to continue.

The precise behavior depends on the zmq_socket type as well as any other configuration you have done on it (setting the high-water mark, for example).